# Creating a new anaconda environment available to all users

Tags: windows, python, anaconda

We are a group of users using the same multi user anaconda installation on a server.
I have installed a new virtual environment using the command below. I want the new environment available to all users. It is windows system.

```
conda create -p ...\Anaconda3\envs\newEnv python=3.9 anaconda
```

The installation seems successful and I can use the new environment and it is visible for others when typing "conda env list" and they can also activate the new environment but when trying to do stuff like typing "python" or spyder in the new environment "Access is denied." is displayed in the prompt. The users should have full access to the ...\Anaconda3\envs\newEnv inherited from the parent folder but when reviewing the files for example python.exe this does not seem to be the case.

I tried to give the user group read/write permission to the folder using folder properties/security tab. But this did not work ("Failed to Enumerate Objects in the Container") so I had to do it using the command prompt according to these [instructions](https://thegeekpage.com/solved-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container-windows-10-error/)

Now it seems to work but I guess there is a better way to install the new environment so that is accessible for all users directly, any ideas?

BR
Erik